# How to suppress title tooltip of SVG in Angular mat-icon?

Tags: html, angular, svg, angular-material

A SVG file used in a mat-icon contains a `<title>` element which gets displayed:

[image: mat-icon with title from SVG file]

However, I don't want this tooltip (elem/ic-21-outline-list-M) to be displayed (because there is already a tooltip on the surrounding element).

The relevant HTML code is this:

```
<mat-icon svgIcon="listM"></mat-icon>
```

Setting `title=""`, `matTooltip=""`, or `alt=""` didn't help.

How can I suppress this tooltip?

Comment: Does this work for you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54318292/how-to-remove-tooltip-from-mat-icon-button-in-an-electron-application

Comment: @jamesioppolo Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't remove the tooltip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the title from the svg takes precedence. But you can just open the svg in a text editor and look for the title tag and remove it.